# WPF using converter in datatemplate created from xaml text and XamlReader on phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I'm generating a DataTemplate using a text xaml like this:

```
var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml.ToString());
```

One of the elements is a CheckBox bound with it's converter pointing to a StaticResource:

```
    StringBuilder xaml = new StringBuilder();
    xaml.AppendFormat(@"          <CheckBox");
    xaml.AppendFormat(@" IsChecked=""{{Binding [{0}], Converter={{StaticResource stringValueToBoolConverter}}, Mode=TwoWay}}""", header.ID);
    xaml.AppendFormat(@" />");
```

The presence of this converter reference in the text causes an exception caught in the Application_UnhandledException on phone. The message looks like this:

```
-       InnerException  {System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure_WithDesiredSize(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure_WithDesiredSize(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)}   System.Exception
```

The template is used to create a row in a listbox and the control has the converter declared in it's resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:StringValueToBoolConverter x:Key="stringValueToBoolConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I suppose that at some creation step, the object creation process of xaml->objects can't find the converter - is there a way to get around it?

**Addition

I also just tested adding a Loaded for the check box - same assert as adding the converter

```
StringBuilder xaml = new StringBuilder();
xaml.AppendFormat(@"          <CheckBox");
xaml.AppendFormat(@" IsChecked=""{{Binding [{0}],  Mode=TwoWay}}""", header.ID);
xaml.AppendFormat(@" Loaded=""FrameworkElement_OnLoaded""");
```

Maybe there's a way to provide this context to the loader?

Answer (score 0):

> The template is used to create a row in a listbox and the control has the converter declared in it's resources:

Why not instead load the data into a preloaded listbox and use ItemsSource to bind to a collection loaded from your file? And use a visibility converter to show/hide date. What you're doing seems needlessly complicated for what it actually does.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm attempting to create a datagrid-like UI using a ListBox where each ListBox item is a Grid of a single row. The number of columns and the type of data is not known at compile time. Any column could be a bool or string type and I need to manage the conversion from the data in the case of a bool (CheckBox)

Comment: Your stringbuilder  is essentially rebuilding xaml and injecting it into a control.Parsing it into an ienumerable<bool> and using that as an ItemsSource={binding boolIenumerableWhateverThisPropertyIsCalled} within the datatemplate component accessing said property is also valid. The data template can then be activated by calling the respective visiblity container to draw it on the screen. More info about datagrids here [link]http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagrid and dataTemplate from [link]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way

Comment: The string builder is creating either checkbox or textbox elements determined by some schema data - the actual origin data is all strings, so I both need to create the correct ui element and then bind to the data (with a converter in case the string data is supposed to be evaluated as a boolean) but this is unknown at design-time and the data I get for the row is a dictionary of <string, string>