# WPF phone 8 The attachable property Resources was not found in type DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to kick out a DataTemplate at runtime for the ListBox's ContentTemplateSelected. The data types and values are not known at runtime. Here's an example of one. When I call this:

```
var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml.ToString());
```

on the generated xaml:

```
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:DSI.MyProject.Converters;assembly=DSI.MyProject"
>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <converters:StringValueToBoolConverter x:Key="stringValueToBoolConverter" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>   
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="128" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" >
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding [CheckEd], Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
      </Border>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I get the error:

The attachable property Resources was not found in type DataTemplate

Am I missing something in the includes?

Even though this example doesn't use it, the converter will be used in the IsChecked binding.

It seems to work for this person:
[Dynamically added DataTemplate - StaticResource for Converter can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140382/dynamically-added-datatemplate-staticresource-for-converter-cant-be-found?rq=1)

My original issue: [WPF using converter in datatemplate created from xaml text and XamlReader on phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350731/wpf-using-converter-in-datatemplate-created-from-xaml-text-and-xamlreader-on-pho/28353259#28353259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing WPF behavior with the SilverLight XAML distribution for Windows and Windows Phone 8. Unfortunately, [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) is a property of the [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.aspx) base class, while [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.aspx) derives from the lower level [DependencyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.105).aspx) class. As such, it does not support a resource collection.

As a fix, consider making the converter part of your Application or Page resources rather than part of the DataTemplate directly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, your suggested fix is my initial problem - my top-level is a <UserControl> and when I add the converter to it's resources I get an exception when loading the xaml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350731/wpf-using-converter-in-datatemplate-created-from-xaml-text-and-xamlreader-on-pho/28353259#28353259

Comment: I'm a little concerned about your method for selecting templates. It seems you're actually attempting to parse XAML when it would be easier to either select a static instance of a DataTemplate resource or UserControl resource and assign it programmatically, and this may be the source of your woes in making use of the converter. The problem may in fact be architectural.

Comment: I'm concerned too ;) I can see how you can make a selection based on the datatemplate's target type if you have a strongly-typed object. What I have is a 'row' of strings (don't know how many columns at design-time some of which need to be evaluated as booleans again not known until run-time.) I'm trying to dynamically create a grid element of these values that occupy each row of a list box.

Comment: ...And that part works fine - the last step I need is to apply the converter to the binding (for evaluating the string data as true or false for boolean data) - that's the part that I can't seem to resolve when the static resource to the converter resides in that xaml string

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the original question.